# How to pass a lot of data to Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have Aura component which need to pass a lot of data to Visualforce for PDF rendering (two tables). What is the best way to do it? I guess it is not a good idea to pass data through url parameters because data amount is too large for URL params (more than 2500 chars)

Comment: I am not posting this as an answer as I have not tried it yet. But you can save the data in a object -> Pass the object to VF page -> Query the data back in VFPage via sforce, then create the table as required.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Interesting solution, thanks

Comment: mind specifying how much, a lot of data is?